# Flicking when switch filter with GPUImageStillCamera

Tags: ios, objective-c, filter, gpuimage, chain

I have some filter issues when dealing with GPUImageStillCamera.
In my app, I use 2 preview views with 2 filters and one stillCamera.
Like this

```
[_stillCamera addTarget:_frontFilter]; [_frontFilter addTarget:_frontView];
[_stillCamera addTarget:_backFilter]; [_backFilter addTarget:_backView];
```

Everything is ok, but when I change the filter I have problems

```
- (void)switchFilter
{
    [_stillCamera removeTarget:_frontFilter];
    [_stillCamera removeTarget:_backFilter];
    [_frontFilter removeTarget:_frontView];
    [_backFilter removeTarget:_backView];

    // Make sure everything is removed
    [_stillCamera removeAllTargets];

    // Get new filter
    _frontFilter = _arrGPUImageFilter[0];
    _backFilter = _arrGPUImageFilter[1];

    // Add target
    [_stillCamera addTarget:_frontFilter];
    [_frontFilter addTarget:_frontView];
    [_stillCamera addTarget:_backFilter];
    [_backFilter addTarget:_backView];
}
```

By the time I switch the filter, there is some flicker in the front view, and I'm still stuck after one week; I tried to fix, but no hope.

PS: When I use GPUImageFilterPipeline like in this link: [Switching between filter chains using GPUImage Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254210/switching-between-filter-chains-using-gpuimage-framework)

```
- (void)switchFilter
{
    if (!_piplineFront)
    {
        GPUImageFilter *emptyFilter = [[GPUImageFilter alloc] init];
        NSArray *emptyArray = @[emptyFilter];

        _piplineFront = [[GPUImageFilterPipeline alloc] initWithOrderedFilters:emptyArray input:_stillCamera output:_frontView];
    }
    if (!_piplineBack)
    {
        GPUImageFilter *emptyFilter = [[GPUImageFilter alloc] init];
        NSArray *emptyArray = @[emptyFilter];

        _piplineBack = [[GPUImageFilterPipeline alloc] initWithOrderedFilters:emptyArray input:_stillCamera output:_backView];
    }

    // Get filter
    _frontFilter = _arrGPUImageFilter[frontIndex];
    _backFilter = _arrGPUImageFilter[backIndex];

    [_piplineBack replaceAllFilters:@[_backFilter]];
    [_piplineFront replaceAllFilters:@[_frontFilter]];
}
```

I can't use two GPUImagePipelines together. The backView or frontView are not showing.

I'd like further help. Please.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the filter chain (something like `for (id<GPUImageInput> target in [_frontFilter targets] ) { NSLog(@"%@", target); } `) ? Did you try calling `removeAllTargets` on your filters too ?

Comment: I've done with it. I have to hide it when applying new filter and show it again :)